# How can I make Windows Explorer show file modified date instead of created date?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management

The date shown in Windows Explorer in Windows 7 shows by default the "created date", can I change it to modified date?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you want to show modified date in Windows Explorer Right click on Date Modified column header, unselect Data Created and select Date Modified.

[image]

Comment: How can I make it permanent for all exist and future folders?