# How do I add the "Date Created" sort-by option to the shell in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sorting

I know how to add it via the context menu, but it never seems to be a permanent option. I would like it to show in all folders without having to continually go back through and add it.

[How can I make Windows Explorer show file modified date instead of created date?](https://superuser.com/questions/212542/how-can-i-make-windows-explorer-show-file-modified-date-instead-of-created-date)

I've looked at this question, so I assume it is the same as going through the context menu seen by right clicking inside the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Make an Explorer window look like you want.
2. Folder context menu (`Alt+T`), Tools » Folder Options » View tab » "Apply to all folders"

[image]

Comment: This will not work if you want to add a "date created" or "date modified" column to ALL folder Types and without breaking the folder types (e.g. leaving your music folder as an Audio type but adding "date modified" to it etc). But you could do it for all folder types separately. However this probably doesn't work in all types of shells, such as various browse for files dialogues.