# Make "Date created" column persistent for a Downloads folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

In Windows 7 there is a shortcut to a Downloads folder in the start menu. I prefer to view my downloads with details, sorted ascending by a `Date created` column, as this shows them ordered by the time I have downloaded, those downloaded most recently sorted down.

This works great, however there is a small annoyance - sometimes when I open the `Downloads` folder, the `Date created` column is no longer there and I have to add it again from the context menu and sort by it again. It is not difficult, but doing this almost daily is annoying.

Is there some way to tell the Windows Explorer to store the view settings somehow for this folder, so that I do not have to set them again and again?

Note: I do not want all my folders to be sorted by `Date created`, as in [How do I add the “Date Created” sort-by option to the shell in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/434577/how-do-i-add-the-date-created-sort-by-option-to-the-shell-in-windows-7), only the Downloads folder.

Comment: But have you done the "apply to all folders" bit recently? In my opinion Windows does not remember individual folder settings well. But it might help to do this one time (the way you want), then modify the Downloads folder and see if it holds.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you achieve it

First setup the Downloads folder as per your liking. So include the "Date Created" column & sort it in the desired order.

[image]

Next, open Folder Options from within this same folder window in Windows Explorer.
On the "View" tab, click on "Apply to Folders". Now this should sort things out.

[image]

Comment: This is already answer to the question I have linked to - however I think  "Apply to Folders" will apply this setting to all folders, while I want it only for Downloads.